# Unexpected end of JSON input: asp.net core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

when select query

```
select * from Permissions where AppId='yZVwUoxKQCu'  FOR JSON PATH,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

executes in sql server direct it return full data with array wrapper without unexpected end.when the query read with DataReader in C# it the same query result have unexpected end. the sql execute using below the method.

Query like this

```
var sql = $"select * from Permissions where AppId='{AppId}'  FOR JSON PATH,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES";
            var res = Connection.ExecuteScalarCommand(sql);
```

```
 public static String ExecuteScalarCommand(string sql)
        {
            string CS = DbConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
            string val = "";
            try
            {

                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                val = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            return val;

        }
```

The output given by sql server direct is given.its expected output.

```
[{"Id":49,"IsCreatable":0,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":29,"Title":"Season","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":1,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":50,"IsCreatable":0,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":29,"Title":"Categories","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":2,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":51,"IsCreatable":2,"IsViewable":2,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":29,"Title":"Tabs","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":3,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":52,"IsCreatable":1,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":29,"Title":"Fields","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":4,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":53,"IsCreatable":1,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":29,"Title":"ContentBlock","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":5,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":54,"IsCreatable":1,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":29,"Title":"User","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":6,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":55,"IsCreatable":1,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":29,"Title":"Roles","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":7,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":56,"IsCreatable":0,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":30,"Title":"Season","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":1,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":57,"IsCreatable":0,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":30,"Title":"Categories","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":2,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":58,"IsCreatable":2,"IsViewable":2,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":30,"Title":"Tabs","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":3,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":59,"IsCreatable":1,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":30,"Title":"Fields","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":4,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":60,"IsCreatable":1,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":30,"Title":"ContentBlock","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":5,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":61,"IsCreatable":1,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":30,"Title":"User","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":6,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":62,"IsCreatable":1,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":30,"Title":"Roles","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":7,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":42,"IsCreatable":0,"IsViewable":0,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":0,"RoleId":28,"Title":"Season","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":1,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":43,"IsCreatable":1,"IsViewable":0,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":28,"Title":"Categories","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":2,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":44,"IsCreatable":1,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":28,"Title":"Tabs","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":3,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":45,"IsCreatable":1,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":28,"Title":"Fields","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":4,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":46,"IsCreatable":1,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":28,"Title":"ContentBlock","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":5,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":47,"IsCreatable":1,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":28,"Title":"User","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":6,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":48,"IsCreatable":0,"IsViewable":0,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":0,"RoleId":28,"Title":"Roles","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":7,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"}]
```

but out put from asp.net core is

```
[{"Id":49,"IsCreatable":0,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":29,"Title":"Season","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":1,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":50,"IsCreatable":0,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":29,"Title":"Categories","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":2,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":51,"IsCreatable":2,"IsViewable":2,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":29,"Title":"Tabs","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":3,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":52,"IsCreatable":1,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":29,"Title":"Fields","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":4,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":53,"IsCreatable":1,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":29,"Title":"ContentBlock","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":5,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":54,"IsCreatable":1,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":29,"Title":"User","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":6,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":55,"IsCreatable":1,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":29,"Title":"Roles","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":7,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":56,"IsCreatable":0,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":30,"Title":"Season","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":1,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":57,"IsCreatable":0,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":30,"Title":"Categories","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":2,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":58,"IsCreatable":2,"IsViewable":2,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":30,"Title":"Tabs","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":3,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":59,"IsCreatable":1,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":30,"Title":"Fields","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":4,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":60,"IsCreatable":1,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":30,"Title":"ContentBlock","UserId":60,"PermissionTitleId":5,"AppId":"yZVwUoxKQCu"},{"Id":61,"IsCreatable":1,"IsViewable":1,"IsDeletable":1,"IsUpdatable":1,"RoleId":30,"Title":"User","UserId":60,"PermissionT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.8) has a character limit:

> The first column of the first row in the result set, or a null
>   reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the result set is empty.
>   Returns a maximum of 2033 characters.

To overcome that you will need to use a different function, like [ExecuteReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_ExecuteReader_System_Data_CommandBehavior_).

Comment: `var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                  while (rdr.Read())
             {
                      res = res+ rdr[0].ToString();
                   }
                rdr.Close();` its worked

Comment: @samjadps I was happy to help.